# How to check font size of body text in IEEEtran Conference template?

Tags: ieeetran

The specifications are

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
```

I need font size of 10 for body text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Default font size is 10pt. However, you can declare font size with `\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}`

Comment: Thanks @Zarko for clarification!